# Where do you use Java Channels?

Tags: java, io

I have only used Java Channels and BufferedOutputStream and the input counter part for reading and writing simple integers and some strings here and there to the file.
However I do not understand the use of all these classes when there is `java.util.Scanner` class that provides easy ways to read and write to the files.
Java veterans please tell me the use of Channels and Streams over Scanner.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html ?

Comment: For one thing, java.util.Scanner can *not* be used to write to files.

Comment: @MartijnVerburg: Nope, I was using Ivor Horton's book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Java Channels for applications that have much more traffic coming to them, not just for simple stuff. Same goes, (kind of) for buffered IO. If you're writing to a file, and you're using any considerable amount of output, then you're going to want to use a buffered IO driver. If you're reading from a file, and don't have to read that much information, use Scanner, otherwise, use buffered IO.